# Osmconvert command-line window closes when I press Return

Tags: openstreetmap, windows, command-line

I am dealing with Open street map Data.
I want to convert some of [these](http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/Industry/) .o5m files to .osm format so that I can process them in QGIS.

So, I have downloaded [Osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) to run on my Windows XP operating system.
I run the osmconvert.exe file and a black command-line window opens.
But, whatever I type into the command-line, when I press Return or Enter the window disappears and the program closes!

Please could anyone suggest what sort of problem this is that I've run into.
I'm new to command-line computing so apologies if its very obvious.

Many thanks
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first to open a command window, then execute osmconvert.

Here are some hints on opening command windows:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378319/windows-explorer-command-prompt-here

Another choice is to create a batch file with the command, and add a pause command as last line:

```
osmconvert.exe D:\Karten\osm\Geofabrik\germany.osm.pbf -b=8.5,54.2,9.0,54.5 -o=D:\Karten\osm\osmconvert\bbox.osm --complex-ways
pause
```

This lets the command window stay open until you want to close it.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea I could do that in windows. I think Im starting to catch on with the command line too, in that I need to type in everything before executing.

Answer (score 1):

If you type "a" and hit enter, it brings up some information about the program and it will ask you questions to guide you through converting your files. Also, the .exe has to be in the same folder as the source data.

Hope that helps. . .